# Does wp_get_attachment_image_src also work with non-image files?

Tags: images, uploads, attachments

I wish to get the file path to files other than images like PDF or TXT that are uploaded. Should I use wp_get_attachment_image_src or there's other function more suited for non-image attachments.

Answer (score 3):

No, [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) is for image files only. For non-image files, you can use [`get_attached_file()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) to get the full filesystem path to the attachment file. And to get the full URL, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/).